# Outer join with Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have two tables, `User` and `UserBusinessPartnerIds`

`User(id, name, email, whatever)`

`UserBusinessPartnerIds(userId, bpId)`

I am trying to retrieve a user and a list of business partner ids.

The following query works fine!

```
database withSession { implicit session: Session =>
      val query = (for {
        (user, userBpid) <- Users leftJoin UserBusinessPartners on (_.id is _.userId)
          if user.email === email &&
             user.password === password &&
             user.active === true &&
             userBpid.dateFrom < today &&
             userBpid.dateTo > today
      } yield (user.id, userBpid.bpId.?))

      val results = query.list

      results.headOption.map( row  => User(row._1, email, password, results.map(_._2).flatten.toSet))
    }
```

Granted, the end of the code is heinous; but whatever.

The problem is, I wish to do an OUTER join. So if a user doesn't have a corresponding row to a business partner id in the other table, I still want to get that user.

Any ideas?

edit - Edited the question to actually be correct. I still want to return a user even if they dont have business partner ids associated with them

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, what does the generated sql look like? Should be a left outer join.

I suspect the issue is with:

```
userBpid.dateFrom < today && userBpid.dateTo > today
```

As the user + null user-partner row(s) cannot be returned due to applying conditions to potentially null values; i.e. they will never return true when an associated business partner id row does not exist.

As a test, do a `println(q.sqlStatement)` or look in your query log and run the query manually with and without above query condition.

**EDIT**
Not tested, but try this, aliasing user business table, one inner, one outer. You may get a non-unique table alias compiler error, has happened to me in a previous attempt to work some outer join magic

```
val q = 
  for{
    (u,upo) <- Users leftJoin UserBusinessPartners on (_.id is _.userId)
      if(u.email is email) && (u.password is password) && (u.active is true)
    up <- UserBusinessPartners
      if(u.id is up.userId) && (up.dateFrom < today) && (up.dateTo > today)
    _ <- Query groupBy(u.id)
  } yield (u.id, upo.bpId.?)
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, should've pointed out that this is the problem. How do we "optionally" check the dateRanges when they can potentially be not returned.

Comment: With just user outer join on user-partner you can't supply the dateFrom/dateTo conditions. If you user inner join user-partner1 and outer join user-partner2 then you should be in business.

Comment: I dont think I quite follow, care to edit your answer to show an example for some sweet, sweet karma?

Comment: Sadly, your proposed solution doesn't seem to be doing the trick; it's still not doing an outer join. It doesn't have any compiler problems at least!

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the UserBusinessPartners table before the join and that will give you users who have no business partners.
something like :

```
database withSession { implicit session: Session =>
  userBP = UserBusinessPartners.filter(ubp => ubp.dateFrom < today && ubp.dateTo > today)
  val query = (for {
    (user, userbp) <- Users leftJoin userBP on (_.id is _.userId)
      if user.email === email &&
         user.password === password &&
         user.active === true 
  } yield (user.id, userbp.bpId.?))

  val results = query.list

  results.headOption.map( row  => User(row._1, email, password, results.map(_._2).flatten.toSet))
}
```

The filter will show you a view on table with only desired business partners, the left join will list all users.

Your query failed because of :

> userBpid.dateFrom < today && userBpid.dateTo > today

Because a row selected with null userBpid will get filtered out because of above condition.